# Python Selenium get page within for loop

Tags: python, selenium

I have a list of pages which have similar DOM structure.

I'm trying to crawl them by python selenium within a for loop, but always get the first page information.

my code looks like:

```
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, wait)
    // always get name in first page
    name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.company-name')))
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: How are you getting the url?

Comment: @0m3r Crawler from another page. Make sure they are valid.

Comment: Can you post full code?

Comment: As suggested by other users, please post the parts of your code that are missing. Try to complete your questions so more people from the community can understand what your problem is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Finally solve my problem!

Just to wait for url change, and I modify my code as below:

```
for new_url in urls:
    current_url = driver.current_url
    driver.get(new_url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, wait)
    // wait until url change
    WebDriverWait(driver, wait).until(EC.url_changes(current_url))
    // get new name
    name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.company-name')))
```